# Create dataframe from dataframe in list with the maximum value in a column in R

Tags: r, list, max

I want to select the dataframe with the highest numbers in the 'value' column from a list of dataframes. In this case it will be dataframe3. I want to make a new dataframe from that selected dataframe.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Here is an example dataset:

```
list <- list()

dataframe1 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("1","1","2","5","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","4","3","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","2","5","3","3","5"),
                         value = c("14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500","14.32500"))

list[[1]] <- dataframe1

dataframe2 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
           gr = c("5","4","3","5","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","2","3","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","4","4","4","4","4"),
           value = c("12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000","12.59000"))
list[[2]] <- dataframe2

dataframe3 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("5","3","3","5","5","5","5","3","5","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                         value = c("20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915","20.06915"))

list[[3]] <- dataframe3

dataframe4 <- data.frame(sample = c("OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5046___d","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_a","OP5054DNAa","OP5048___c","OP2645ii_d","OP5048___b","OP5047___a","OP5048___h","OP5053DNAb","OP3088i__a","OP5048___g","OP5053DNAa","OP5049___a","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___c","OP5044___c","OP2413iiia","OP5054DNAc","OP5046___e","OP5054DNAb","OP5044___a","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP2413iiib","OP5051DNAa","OP5048___d","OP5044___b","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAc","OP5051DNAb","OP5053DNAc","OP5047___b","OP5043___b","OP5043___a","OP5052DNAa"),
                         gr = c("2","2","2","3","4","5","5","3","2","2","2","4","5","1","1","3","2","1","2","5","5","5","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2","1","1","2","2","5","3","3","5"),
                         value = c("18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500","18.32500"))

list[[4]] <- dataframe4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the highest numbers in the 'value' column"? The highest maximum value per column, or the mean, median, sum, harmonic mean...?

Comment: @IgorF. I might have phrased that badly. I mean the highest value across all the dataframes in the list. Essentially, I want to select the dataframe which has the highest 'value' column. All the values in the same dataframe will be equal because they represent the mean of another process not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert data to appropriate types (so as to enable maximum calc):

```
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){type.convert(x)})
```

Find the index of the df in the list with the maximum value, and extract it out into new df:

```
new_df <- df_list[[which.max(lapply(df_list, function(x){max(x$value)}))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```r
# max_df is a list to store the max of each value in the list
max_df = vector("list", length(list))

for(i in seq_along(list)){
  max_df[i] <- max(as.numeric(as.character(list[[i]][["value"]])))
}
#max_df now has the max of each list 
# which reports the position of the max 
which(unlist(max_df) == max(unlist(max_df)))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be `list`s? You can make one big single data frame, with a column `frame.nr` to identify its place in your list (which you actually don't need), and filter by the highest value. Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe1 %>% mutate(frame.nr=1) %>%
  rbind(dataframe2 %>% mutate(frame.nr=2)) %>%
  rbind(dataframe3 %>% mutate(frame.nr=3)) %>%
  rbind(dataframe4 %>% mutate(frame.nr=4)) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) -> df.all

df.all %>%
  filter(frame.nr ==
    df.all %>%
      group_by(frame.nr) %>%
      summarise(max.value=max(value)) %>%
      filter(max.value == max(max.value)) %>%
      select(frame.nr) %>%
      unlist
) %>%
  select(-frame.nr)
```